# Browse a column and change in it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need help please.  I read a file.csv using pandas.  I'd like to create a function to change the dataframe, but only in one column.  For example, if I find a value equal to 0, I will change it to "setosa", so I need to browse all of the values of the column

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
iris=load_iris()
iris.feature_names
iris.target_names
irispn=pd.DataFrame(iris.data)
irispn.columns=iris.feature_names
irispn['Target']=iris.target
irispn.value_counts
0 
0
0 
0
0 
0
0
```

I'd like to change all the 0s.

Comment: What is the name of the column you want to change the zero's? And what is the type of column? You can check that with `print(irisvpn.dtypes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
d = {0:'setosa',
     1:'versicolor',
     2:'virginica'}
irispn.Target = irispn.Target.map(d)
```

Comment: You are just mapping values in `irispn.Target` (which are keys in the dictionary `d`) to their corresponding values in `d`.